# How to call https services and how to import .crt file in android studio project

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio, ssl-certificate, webservices-client

actually, i have created one project. in that project, i am calling web services through HTTP helper classes. now those services are becoming secured they put some SSL certificates to call those services.

what my questions are

how to import .crt file in Android studio project?
how to call those https services?

please help me with this problem

Thank you